# Unable to fetch data using powershell as external data source

Tags: terraform

```
# main.tf
data "external" "extDateTime" {
  program = ["pwsh", "${path.module}/getDateTime.ps1"]
}

output "value" {
  value = "${data.external.extDateTime.result.dateTime}"
}
```

**This is the Powershell file getDateTime.ps1 code section**

```
# getDateTime.ps1
$DateTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
Write-Output "{""dateTime"": $DateTime}"
```

Then I run the following command: terraform plan

> Error: Unexpected External Program Results with data.external.extDateTime, on main.tf line 26, in data "external" "extDateTime":
> 26: program = ["Powershell.exe", "${path.module}/getDateTime.ps1"]
> The data source received unexpected results after executing the program. Program output must be a JSON encoded map of string keys and string values.
> Program: C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe
> **Result Error: invalid character '{' after top-level value**

My understanding is the PS script has to return in JSON format but I keep getting the Result Error.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the JSON values are correctly formatted as strings (using back ticks to escape double quotes):

```
$DateTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
Write-Output "{`"dateTime`": `"$DateTime`"}"
```

As per the Terraform docs for the [external](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source#external-program-protocol) data source:

> The JSON object contains the contents of the query argument and its values will always be strings.

Another way that this can be done is to create a PowerShell custom object and convert it to JSON:

```
$DateTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss"
$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
  dateTime     = $DateTime
}
ConvertTo-Json $myObject
```

If you need the output to be a number, you can use the [`tonumber()`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/tonumber) function:

```
output "value" {
  value = tonumber(data.external.extDateTime.result.dateTime)
}
```

Comment: cody - I tried both of your examples provided and the same exact error was returned I provided above.  
Tried running the terraform plan command from PS 5 and 7 and got the same error.
Tried wrapping the Write-Output with [] and got the same error.
Tested the PS file by itself and the output is fine, even ran it through a JSON linter and it passed review.

Comment: Terraform trace error - [ERROR] vertex "data.external.extDateTime" error: Unexpected External Program Results

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what the issue was.  I was running terraform commands in PS 7 (pwsh.exe) but my data.external program was calling PS 5 (powershell.exe).  Once I updated to the following: program = ["pwsh.exe", "${path.module}/getDateTime.ps1"] it worked fine.  The error message referring to the { was misleading me.  Thanks again Cody.

Comment: Good to know. When I'd run the program I hadn't noticed this (I'm running `pwsh` from macOS). I did test the output though and without quotes on the `$DateTime` variable (treated as a number, which is okay in JSON but won't work as per what 's written in my answer) the following error will occur: "Result Error: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string"